# Data com bootstrap não roda no meu projeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Preciso colocar um componente para selecionar datas num filtro do meu projeto. Como uso bootstrap, preciso colocar as datas com esse componente. Acontece que os exemplos que eu peguei na internet, não consegui fazer funcionar, um deles [aqui](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

Qualuer ajuda, agradeço.

Coloquei esse cara no meu .js

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
```

E esse na minha view sem o value, sem data padrão.

```
<div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
  <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012">
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: entao coloque os testes que você fez, conforme diz as regras da comunidade. assim o pessoal ira te ajudar

Comment: Essa linha do script roda antes ou depois do input ter sido adicionado ao DOM?

Comment: Você fez os includes do css e js do datepicker? Parece funcionar normalmente, veja http://jsfiddle.net/uya9b4d8/

Comment: Não tinha os includes. Aí incluir o .js do datepicker e também o css e mesmo assim, não funciona e no fiddle sem problemas. Apareceram uns erros(404 e 500) e antes não havia, apenas que não reconhecia a função, mas depois do include o erro sumiu e apareceu esse. Um deles eu resolvo aqui, acho que resolvendo um, resolvo o outro. Depois posto, após remover o erro para ver se funcionou ou não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme seu comando:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
```

Se está exatamente como você falou, precisa adicionar a **classe css** `datepicker` no seu **input**.

```
<input class="span2 datepicker" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012">
```

Caso contrário o *jQuery* não encontra o elemento para então aplicar o plugin.

Comment: É isso mesmo, Tiago. Obrigado.